# Throw Exception or Return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a function which my controller is calling to check if an account is valid or not.

I was wondering whats the best design to return in the function. Would it be better to throw an exception or return a error message?

**Option 1**, which im currently using

```
public void ValidateLocalAccount(Login dto) {
     var user = _userService.GetUserByUsername(dto.username);
     if (user == null)
           throw new Exception("User does not exist");

     if (user.accountType != AccountType.Local)
           throw new Exception("Account is not local");
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] Login loginDto)
{
    try
    {
          _accountService.ValidateLocalAccount(loginDto);
          return Ok(await _accountService.GetToken(loginDto));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Option 2**, this seems unconventional to me

```
public <bool, string> ValidateLocalAccount(Login dto) {
     var user = _userService.GetUserByUsername(dto.username);
     if (user == null)
           return (false,"User does not exist");

     if (user.accountType != AccountType.Local)
           return (false,"Account is not local");

     return (true,string.empty);
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] Login loginDto)
{
     var res = _accountService.ValidateLocalAccount(loginDto);
     if(!res.item1)
        return BadRequest(res.item2)

     return Ok(await _accountService.GetToken(loginDto));
}
```

Would i be mis-using exceptions from option 1, since im kinda using it to control the flow? Thus my question is when should i choose exceptions over error codes or return null ? Which option is a better design ?. Cheers.

Comment: Off topic IMO: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Ask yourself: Is a user not existing exceptional? Remember also that an exception will have to produce a stack trace, whereas a simple return will not.

Comment: I think it's a good idea not to throw an exception, unless it is an exceptional circumstance. Please take a look at [this post by Matt Warren](https://mattwarren.org/2016/12/20/Why-Exceptions-should-be-Exceptional/).

Comment: Furthermore, as far as I can tell by looking at your code snippet, there are three possible outcomes for the `ValidateLocalAccount`. One is that the user doesn't exist, which would be semantically more correct to return a [404 - Not Foumd], than a [400 - Bad Request]. The second is that the user exists, but isn't a local user, in that case it could either return a [422 - Unprocessable Entity] or even a [500 - Internal Server Error]. Finally, there is the case where everything is valid.

Answer (score 2):

A failed login attempt is by no means exceptional, and therefor you should not use exceptions in such a case. That would be what Eric Lippert is calling a [vexing exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) - so I would definitely go with option #2.

If you are using C# 7.0 or higher, you can return a [value tuple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/), so you could use meaningful names to it's items (rather than Item1 and Item2 in System.Tuple). If you are using an earlier version of c#, you might want to return your own struct or class, for the sake of future maintenance and code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is returning proper status code like `404` (Not found), `401` (Unauthorized) or `500` (Internal Server Error).

Check out the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of HTTP status codes.

P.S. In case of writing an `API`, Returning status code is best practice but if you are writing web apps like razor pages then it is best to return error messages, not an exception.

Comment: thanks im aware of the status code, but my question is on the design of handling logic flows with exceptions vs returns